# A better understanding of named constructors idiom

Tags: c++

I want to make a angle class to be initialized in radians or degrees and I want to return the value and not the Angle object. I found out that named constructors would probably the most efficient way to do this but I am not a 100% sure how I would modify for my case.

```
#pragma once
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
class Angle
{
public:
    static Angle toRadians(double value) 
    {
        return Angle((value * M_PI / 180.0f));
    
    }
    static Angle toDegrees(double value) 
    {
        return Angle(value / 180.0f * M_PI);
    }
private:
    double angle;
    Angle(double value) : angle(value) {};

};

std::cout << Angle::toRadians(19.48); // Should print 0.33999014
```

Comment: If you want a function that takes a degree value as a double and returns a radians value as a double, then just make a `double toRadians(double angle)` function. No need for classes here.

Comment: `value * M_PI / 180.0f` and `value / 180.0f * M_PI` are the same. There's no precedence difference between / and *.

Comment: @doug but the result may be different because that expression is evaluated from left to right. Try with [value =1.2345](https://ideone.com/gTWcto) and see

Comment: @viidawg why on earth do you use `180.0f`? Everything is double but the literal is float. It may not make a difference in this case but it'll result in huge deviation in other cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Angle` class lacks an *invariant*. That is to say, there is nothing that can be said to be true about an arbitrary object of the `Angle` class beyond "it contains a double".

Consider this: If I write the following function:

```
void do_something(Angle delta) {
  // do something
}
```

How am I supposed to work with delta if it can contain either degrees or radians, and I have no way of knowing which it is?

Believe it or not, this is at the root of your struggles with constructors. That's because the main job of a constructor is to put the object in its invariant state. No invariant means no reference point, so it's not clear what the constructor should do.

So let's set an invariant that would let us implement `do_something()` with confidence: "an Angle always contains radians". You could even go to a tighter invariant with "... and that angle is always in the `[-pi, pi[` range".

It's suddenly clear that your `toRadians()` and `toDegrees()` named constructors make no sense in that context. In fact they never really did, but it's obvious now. We want are functions that establish the invariant from their arguments. `fromRadians()` and `fromDegrees()` would make a lot more sense.

```
class Angle {
public:
    static Angle fromRadians(double value) 
    {
        return Angle(value);    
    }
    
    static Angle fromDegrees(double value) 
    {
        return Angle(value / 180.0 * M_PI);
    }

    double asRadians() const {
      return radians;
    }

    double asDegrees() const {
      return radians / M_PI * 180.0;
    }

private:
  Angle(double value) : radians(value) {}
  double radians;
};
```

Note that with the class implemented like this, code using the `Angle` class doesn't even have to be aware of the invariant. The API just says: an Angle can be constructed from either degrees or radians, and can be interpreted as either degrees or radians. You set invariants as landmarks that guide you while implementing the class. Once the class is built, they serve no purpose anymore, until you want to update the code of course.

Next, if you want to be able to easily dump an angle as a human-readable string, you can implement `operator<<(sts::ostream&, const Angle&)` function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Angle& angle) {
  stream << angle.asDegrees() << "deg";
  return stream;
}
```